# Bluetooth Device not working debian wheezy

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, bluetooth, pci

i just installed debian wheezy on msi cx640dx. my bluetooth device not working.
here is some information.

Kernel version:

```
$uname -r
3.2.0-4-amd64
```

when i use `hcitool dev` it don't show any device.

```
$ hcitool dev
Devices:
```

and with scanning it says that i don't have that device:

```
$ sudo hcitool scan
Device is not available: No such device
```

i think following information is may be helpful.

```
$lsmod | grep -i blue
bluetooth             119455  12 btusb,ath3k,rfcomm,bnep
rfkill                 19012  5 cfg80211,bluetooth
crc16                  12343  2 ext4,bluetooth
```

and.

```
$ lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
04:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
```

and this is kernel ring buffer:

```
$ dmesg  |grep -i blue
[    7.408956] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[    7.408977] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    7.408980] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    7.408982] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    7.408987] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    7.460972] Bluetooth: Generic Bluetooth USB driver ver 0.6
[    7.485478] Bluetooth: Atheros AR30xx firmware driver ver 1.0
[    7.537981] Bluetooth: Error loading firmware
[   22.886593] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   22.886602] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   22.886605] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   23.042310] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   23.042316] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
```

Comment: and no the same problem with Centos and still no help with this problem: `uname -r    2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64`. and `lsmod  | grep blue
bluetooth              99271  4 sco,bnep,l2cap,btusb
rfkill                 19255  3 cfg80211,bluetooth`

Comment: It might be useful to remember that bt by design is very low-power at very short-range. I never used bt per see, but in electrical equations it comes down to very low power, in very short range. Your user-self do what he or she thinks should be done, while the OS says power to bt and adjust my settings? Wake-me kinda thing in BIOS? I know, you are running a BIOS-independent OS, so surprise us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your drivers are **Atheros** you first need to add APT `deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ testing main non-free` and then install `firmware-atheros` package.

Answer (score 1):

You need the packages: bluetooth, bluez, libbluetooth3, and possibly other related packages installed.  I'm presuming you have these.

The Atheros firmware is likely the source of your problem.  There is a firmware-Atheros package in non-free, I believe, you might try if it is actually appropriate for your hardware.  You may need to do some research on the hardware you have, and determine which firmware you need, and whether it is available or not.

Once you get it working, I've noted that the KDE KBluedevil bluetooth manager does not work properly, but the blueman bluetooth manager package does.

You may need to run something like:
'sudo hciconfig hci0 sspmode 0'
before it will work, possibly every time.  I haven't extensively tested this, yet.

Comment: When posting answers it is more helpful if you (or someone) as tested the solution. Try and stick to definite answers rather than 'may'. Suggestions can go in comments when you are able to post there.